# How to Run Shell Script at start in VM Virtualbox Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to run a shell script which runs at system login. To try, I used an example script, which has two lines
   `#!/bin/bash`
   `echo “Hello World”`

I Followed all the instructions mentioned on this website `http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-run-a-command-when-boots-up.html`

Even I did some steps such as editing `/etc/rc.local`, but still when I login, I do not see `Hello world` output running on terminal.

Can anyone please explain what is wrong here or may be I am missing something?

Comment: You can check with `sudo /etc/init.d/rc.local start` if the problem is the `rc.local` file. Check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9853/how-can-i-make-rc-local-run-on-startup#401090). Otherwise you can simply add the script to **Startup Applications** such as `bash /path/to/script`

Comment: I checked with `sudo /etc/init.d/rc.local start`  and it shows `ok` and does not work with startup application too...  :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like Ubuntu 16.04 is a systemd system.

Which means you should create a systemd service to run whatever you'd like @ startup.

Look here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers#Example_Systemd_service
After you made your service, use systemctl to enable it on boot for systemd.
`sudo systemctl enable mycustom.service`
To start the service.
`sudo systemctl start mycustom.service`

Comment: I wrote this service file with script                                                        `[Unit]
Description=Start hello world`

`[Service]`
`WorkingDirectory=/home/username/Desktop/`
`Type=forking
ExecStart=/bin/bash hello.sh start
KillMode=process`        

`[Install]`
`WantedBy=multi-user.target`   but no success

Answer (score 0):

You can also schedule a cron job to run once after the reboot command.  The line will need "@reboot  root /path/script.sh"  You can specify whatever user you want to run the script.  To make the result easier to find, you might make that second line something like 
echo "Hello World" > /root/hello.txt

Comment: I did crontab and added the following line:-`@reboot  /home/Desktop/hello.sh`, but no success

Comment: Are you running it as a user called "Desktop?"   I would expect the path to be more like /home/username/Desktop/hello.sh.   I'd direct the output of the script to a file so you can easily see if it ran.

Comment: sorry that was typo, the path is /home/username/Desktop/hello.sh

Answer (score 0):

Add the line in /etc/profile under echo command as follows

```
echo “Hello World”
```

Then execute the following command

```
source /etc/profile
```